# ArrayFormula/Index GoogleSheets Formula Repeating Values

Tags: google-sheets, array-formulas

I am trying to get my sheet to show the rankings of some data, and to pull the team name from my data.

I have managed to get this to work, but when I have 2 teams that have the same score my sheet just displays the first team name rather than recognising that this name has already been used.

The formula is on the first sheet in cell C3 and is referencing cell from the second sheet.
Cell C3 should show Year 5 and C4 should show Year 6.

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1qnuW1BbhFqjaBBBn1JA15sniyvTMROLiFYJMUSI3de0/edit?usp=sharing

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

Just use `SORT`.  Sheets is not excel. Do not try to make it into one.

```
=SORT(Scores!O16:P20,2,0)
```